# Error when writing the method of a button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, syntax-error

I have a button which I want to move when it is clicked.
Why does this code give me error?

"setOnClickListener" is red just like "view"

```
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 ImageButton play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
 ImageButton score = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.score);
 ImageButton options = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.options);

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }

 play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {

         TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 100, 0, 0);
         translateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
         view.startAnimation(translateAnimation);


     }
 });
```

}

Can you help me? Do I have to import something?

Comment: What error? We don't have crystal balls (well, most of us anyway).

Comment: Could show the whole code please? For sure you need `import android.view.View;` , `import android.widget.Button;` and `import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;`. Also change last `v.startAnimation(translateAnimation);` to `view.startAnimation(translateAnimation);`.

Comment: Can you please post the whole trace and the code?

Comment: @mszymborski he said *"setOnClickListener" is red just like "view"*....its a riddle!

Comment: Do it inside `onCreate`.

Comment: I edited, sorry. And I meant that "setOnClickListener" and "view" are colored of red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is mis-arranged. Do this (setting click listener inside `onCreate()`):

```
@Override 
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

     play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
         @Override 
         public void onClick(View view) { 

             TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 100, 0, 0); 
             translateAnimation.setDuration(1000); 
             view.startAnimation(translateAnimation); 

         } 
    }); 
}
```